# SSL dns difference

Tags: ssl

I have a simple question that I should know but I just want to make sure.

I want to buy an ssl certificate but when I called them up to order it they asked me if I wanted the certificate for "example.ca" or "www.example.ca". Not wanting to make a mistake I decided to get clarification from the experts here.

I had not expected this type of question for I believed that they were both virtually identical but after being asked this question I would also like to know in terms of programming if there should be anything else I should know about the difference between the two.

Thanks everyone

Comment: `www` is a sub domain of example.ca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the certificate issued for `www.example.ca`, but make sure the vendor will issue you a certificate that includes the base `example.ca` domain name as a subject alt name. I know that GoDaddy's certificates do this, but you can check with other vendors as they probably do the same. Do not pay the extra cash for a SAN (Subject Alt Name) certificates. These are meant for people trying to protect multiple distinct hostnames (e.g. `www.example.ca`, `www.otherexample.ca`).

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I wanted to know. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of programming, some servers may require a separate IP address for each subdomain, so www.example.ca would be different from shop.example.ca.

Comment: Thank you. I'll be working in subdomains soon enough but right now I'm just working with my main site. But your information has given me a new way of planning for my future subdomains. When would you consider it beneficial to have two different IPs for sub-domain and the main site.

Comment: @Tolure - I really never worry about the benefits by IP address, per se, but I have low transaction volumes. What generally happens is that you have some expanded task going on at the subdomain (video, etc.) and THAT task gets moved to another server - thus, the additional IP address is required, and if that happens to require SSL, your certificate must accomodate.